# How do I package a Python web scraper as a Chrome Extension?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I made an Amazon Web Scraper and I want it work as an extension. What will happen is that it will  display the price if it is lower than the previously recorded price. I don't know Javascript. I went through things like Transcrypt but didn't understand much

Comment: You can't do this, chrome extensions have to be built in JS

Comment: Is any way combine Python and JS? Because I can't rewrite the code in JS.

Comment: Not really, you could compile the python interpreter to ASM.js but the code wil run extremely slowly, plus you would need to re-implement selenium to use the native DOM. I would say it's really not doable

Comment: The only way I've managed to create a chrome plugin written in python is to use Chrome's native messaging API. It's not exactly the real thing - you're still creating the actual plugin in Javascript - it's just that the plugin talks with a python script in your filesystem, communicating through stdin and stdout. It also involves setting registry keys. It's not fun or easy.

Comment: Well in that case what can I do with it? I mean how can I package it for a user? I need something small and fast because the point here is to make the whole process faster than the user going on Amazon and checking the price

Comment: If you really want to do this, you were probably on the right track with Transcrypt as it may be your best bet.   The key to using it effectively is to understand that you are using it to access the functionality of JavaScript libraries, but with Python.  If your Python code relies on a lot of non standard-library Python modules, you may have to rewrite some of your code to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Chrome extensions are written in JS.

The only way to accomplish what you want is to use the extension as a bridge from users browser to your script. You'll need to convert the script into a server of some kind that can accept requests from the extension and respond.